# Ruby - What does it mean by "Void Value Expression"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why am I getting this error and what does it mean by "void value expression".

```
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|
  next if datastore.ems_id == #{provider.id}          
  next if datastore.id == item.storage.id
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end

[----] E, [2023-01-14T16:36:34.265676 #415:10d6b4] ERROR -- automation: Method STDERR: -:218: void value expression
[----] E, [2023-01-14T16:36:34.266714 #415:10d6b4] ERROR -- automation: Method STDERR: next if datastore.id == item.stor...
[----] E, [2023-01-14T16:36:34.267674 #415:10d6b4] ERROR -- automation: Method STDERR: ^~~~
```

But if move the next if condition a bit above then it works fine and no error.

```
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|      
  next if datastore.id == item.storage.id
  next if datastore.ems_id == #{provider.id}          
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end
```

Comment: `#{provider.id}` looks like an accidental comment. Try `provider.id`.

Comment: @steenslag its not a comment. provider.id doesn't get evaluated (next if condition never passes). #{provider.id} does gets evaluated. Its sort of variable expansion. Not sure why just "provider.id" fails.

Comment: Update: I had provider.id to provider.id.to_s and then it works

Comment: I doubt that `#{provider.id}`  gets evaluated, because the `#` starts a comment and does not evaluate anything until the end of the line. It feels to my like you confuse it with string interpolation, because you use curly brackets too. But string interpolation requires being in a string, for example, that `#{...}` is surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: In your case, the problem is not reproducible, since we are getting totally different errors than you get, because `$evm`, `vmdb`, `dialog_hash`, `ems_id`, `ext_management`, `name`, etc. are all undefined. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

Update: it seems like if next statement never evaluates due to  error then we get void value expression error.

In my case  `if datastore.ems_id == #{provider.id}` was wrong so it threw the error.

The following works fine.

```
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|
  next if datastore.ems_id == provider.id
  next if datastore.id == item.storage.id
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end
```